# Effectively searching for collisions in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm working on a project where we store numbers as strings in a MySQL table. We have 7 columns in the following order: id, x_cord, y_cord, s_random, t_random, rownumb and userid.

And what we are looking to do is find 2 rows with the same x_cord and y_cord but different s_random and t_random. I was wondering what kind of efficient possibilities do we have to achieve that, since this table will contain 200 millions of such rows.

Is it better to check every time we add one or better to check the whole table every once in a while?

Thanks

Comment: Numbers as strings? Why?

Comment: If you have a composite index on `(x_cord, y_cord)`, a self-join that finds duplicates should be pretty efficient.

Comment: If these duplicates aren't supposed to be allowed, why don't you just make a unique key on those columns, and the database will prevent creating them in the first place.

Comment: Numbers as strings, because BIGINT isn't big enough, and the duplicates are allowed, we're looking for them.